# spring role based security+roles from a employee database+single signon

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I need to hide navigation in a jsp page using the role of the employee logged in.
The application is logged in using single sign on. I will be getting only username of the user from another application using which i will search in the database to get the employee details. I have a role column in the employee table which i am currently using in javascript to show and hide navigation. How can i set spring security role and use in jsp tag like "hasRole('anyROle'), to show or hide navigation. I have a entity employee which will be used to get data from database, so how can i create authorities using this.

Comment: Please try to clear up your explanation to be more structured and add some code. It's hard for people to try and help when the question is hard to understand or follow

Comment: @Balwant Singh try to put role on session when you logged in. Just make a check using jsp  whether role is Employee then hide other users show. For example: `<% if(!session_role.equals("Employee")){ // Put your navigation code here.}%>`. Feel free to reply if any further explanation needed.

Comment: @Santhucool thank you for your reply, I am able to use this way and its working fine. Do you have any idea how this can be achieved using the spring role based security.

Comment: @ Balwant Singh sorry buddy I don't know Spring frame work.

Comment: Its ok bro @Santhucool. I will find some way to make it work.. Again thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring security expression in JSP to control user

```
<security:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')">
...
</security:authorize>
```

Comment: To use this, I should first set the roles in the spring security right? I should authorize the current user with spring authorize function. That is where i am confused. How can i authorize or set the role from the database.